# Magento 2.2 Override Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager not woking

Tags: magento2.2

I'm trying to override the Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager class with a preference tag, but it's not working.
I've tried to put the tag in the di.xml file in my module and try to put it in /app/etc/di.xml.

Here's my di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager" type="VENDOR\MODULE\SessionManager" />
</config>
```

My VENDOR\MODULE\SessionManager:

```
namespace VENDOR\MODULE;

class SessionManager implements \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
{
    /**
     * Session destroyed threshold in seconds
     */
    const SESSION_DESTROYED_THRESHOLD = 300;

/**
 * Default options when a call destroy()
 *
 * Description:
 * - send_expire_cookie: whether or not to send a cookie expiring the current session cookie
 * - clear_storage: whether or not to empty the storage object of any stored values
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $defaultDestroyOptions = ['send_expire_cookie' => TRUE, 'clear_storage' => TRUE];

/**
 * URL host cache
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected static $urlHostCache = [];

/**
 * Validator
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\ValidatorInterface
 */
protected $validator;

/**
 * Request
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
 */
protected $request;

/**
 * SID resolver
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface
 */
protected $sidResolver;

/**
 * Session config
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface
 */
protected $sessionConfig;

/**
 * Save handler
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface
 */
protected $saveHandler;

/**
 * Storage
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Session\StorageInterface
 */
protected $storage;

/**
 * Cookie Manager
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface
 */
protected $cookieManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
 */
protected $cookieMetadataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
 */
private $appState;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http                    $request
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface        $sidResolver
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface      $sessionConfig
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface        $saveHandler
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\ValidatorInterface          $validator
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Session\StorageInterface            $storage
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface       $cookieManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State                           $appState
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolverInterface $sidResolver,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface $sessionConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandlerInterface $saveHandler,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\ValidatorInterface $validator,
    \Magento\Framework\Session\StorageInterface $storage,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
)
{
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->sidResolver = $sidResolver;
    $this->sessionConfig = $sessionConfig;
    $this->saveHandler = $saveHandler;
    $this->validator = $validator;
    $this->storage = $storage;
    $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    $this->appState = $appState;

    // I put a var_dump to test the script
    var_dump('test');
    die();
    // Enable session.use_only_cookies
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
    $this->start();
}

/**
 * This method needs to support sessions with APC enabled
 * @return void
 */
public function writeClose()
{
    session_write_close();
}

/**
 * Storage accessor method
 *
 * @param string $method
 * @param array  $args
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    if (!\in_array(substr($method, 0, 3), ['get', 'set', 'uns', 'has'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf('Invalid method %s::%s(%s)', \get_class($this), $method, print_r($args, 1))
        );
    }
    $return = \call_user_func_array([$this->storage, $method], $args);
    return $return === $this->storage ? $this : $return;
}

/**
 * Configure session handler and start session
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException
 * @return $this
 */
public function start()
{

    if (!$this->isSessionExists()) {
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('session_start');

        try {
            $this->appState->getAreaCode();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                    'Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.'
                ),
                $e
            );
        }

        // Need to apply the config options so they can be ready by session_start
        $this->initIniOptions();
        $this->registerSaveHandler();
        if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
            // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
            session_write_close();
            session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
        }
        $sid = $this->sidResolver->getSid($this);
        // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
        $this->setSessionId($sid);
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed']) && $_SESSION['destroyed'] < time() - self::SESSION_DESTROYED_THRESHOLD) {
            $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => TRUE]);
        }
        $this->validator->validate($this);
        try {
            $this->renewCookie($sid);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException $e) {
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieSizeLimitReachedException $e) {
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException $e) {
        }

        register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);

        $this->_addHost();
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('session_start');
    }
    $this->storage->init($_SESSION ?? []);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Renew session cookie to prolong session
 *
 * @param null|string $sid If we have session id we need to use it instead of old cookie value
 * @return $this
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieSizeLimitReachedException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException
 */
private function renewCookie($sid)
{
    if (!$this->getCookieLifetime()) {
        return $this;
    }
    //When we renew cookie, we should aware, that any other session client do not
    //change cookie too
    $cookieValue = $sid ?: $this->cookieManager->getCookie($this->getName());
    if ($cookieValue) {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
        $metadata->setPath($this->sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
        $metadata->setDomain($this->sessionConfig->getCookieDomain());
        $metadata->setDuration($this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime());
        $metadata->setSecure($this->sessionConfig->getCookieSecure());
        $metadata->setHttpOnly($this->sessionConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            $this->getName(),
            $cookieValue,
            $metadata
        );
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Register save handler
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function registerSaveHandler()
{
    return session_set_save_handler(
        [$this->saveHandler, 'open'],
        [$this->saveHandler, 'close'],
        [$this->saveHandler, 'read'],
        [$this->saveHandler, 'write'],
        [$this->saveHandler, 'destroy'],
        [$this->saveHandler, 'gc']
    );
}

/**
 * Does a session exist
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isSessionExists()
{
    return !(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE && !headers_sent());
}

/**
 * Additional get data with clear mode
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @param bool   $clear
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getData($key = '', $clear = FALSE)
{
    $data = $this->storage->getData($key);
    if ($clear && isset($data)) {
        $this->storage->unsetData($key);
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Retrieve session Id
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSessionId()
{
    return session_id();
}

/**
 * Retrieve session name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return session_name();
}

/**
 * Set session name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    session_name($name);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Destroy/end a session
 *
 * @param  array $options
 * @return void
 */
public function destroy(array $options = NULL)
{
    $options = $options ?? [];
    $options = array_merge($this->defaultDestroyOptions, $options);

    if ($options['clear_storage']) {
        $this->clearStorage();
    }

    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        return;
    }

    session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
    session_destroy();
    if ($options['send_expire_cookie']) {
        try {
            $this->expireSessionCookie();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException $e) {
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException $e) {
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Unset all session data
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function clearStorage()
{
    $this->storage->unsetData();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Cookie domain
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCookieDomain()
{
    return $this->sessionConfig->getCookieDomain();
}

/**
 * Retrieve cookie path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCookiePath()
{
    return $this->sessionConfig->getCookiePath();
}

/**
 * Retrieve cookie lifetime
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getCookieLifetime()
{
    return $this->sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime();
}

/**
 * Specify session identifier
 *
 * @param   string|null $sessionId
 * @return  $this
 */
public function setSessionId($sessionId)
{
    $this->_addHost();
    if ($sessionId !== NULL && preg_match('#^[0-9a-zA-Z,-]+$#', $sessionId)) {
        session_id($sessionId);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * If session cookie is not applicable due to host or path mismatch - add session id to query
 *
 * @param string $urlHost can be host or url
 * @return string {session_id_key}={session_id_encrypted}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function getSessionIdForHost($urlHost)
{
    $httpHost = $this->request->getHttpHost();
    if (!$httpHost) {
        return '';
    }

    $urlHostArr = explode('/', $urlHost, 4);
    if (!empty($urlHostArr[2])) {
        $urlHost = $urlHostArr[2];
    }
    $urlPath = empty($urlHostArr[3]) ? '' : $urlHostArr[3];

    if (!isset(self::$urlHostCache[$urlHost])) {
        $urlHostArr = explode(':', $urlHost);
        $urlHost = $urlHostArr[0];
        $sessionId = $httpHost !== $urlHost && !$this->isValidForHost($urlHost) ? $this->getSessionId() : '';
        self::$urlHostCache[$urlHost] = $sessionId;
    }

    return $this->isValidForPath($urlPath) ? self::$urlHostCache[$urlHost] : $this->getSessionId();
}

/**
 * Check if session is valid for given hostname
 *
 * @param string $host
 * @return bool
 */
public function isValidForHost($host)
{
    $hostArr = explode(':', $host);
    $hosts = $this->_getHosts();
    return !empty($hosts[$hostArr[0]]);
}

/**
 * Check if session is valid for given path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return bool
 */
public function isValidForPath($path)
{
    $cookiePath = trim($this->getCookiePath(), '/') . '/';
    if ($cookiePath === '/') {
        return TRUE;
    }

    $urlPath = trim($path, '/') . '/';
    return strpos($urlPath, $cookiePath) === 0;
}

/**
 * Register request host name as used with session
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _addHost()
{
    $host = $this->request->getHttpHost();
    if (!$host) {
        return $this;
    }

    $hosts = $this->_getHosts();
    $hosts[$host] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY] = $hosts;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get all host names where session was used
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getHosts()
{
    return $_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY] ?? [];
}

/**
 * Clean all host names that were registered with session
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _cleanHosts()
{
    unset($_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY]);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Renew session id and update session cookie
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function regenerateId()
{
    if (headers_sent()) {
        return $this;
    }

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
        // Regenerate the session
        session_regenerate_id();
        $newSessionId = session_id();
        $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $newSessionId;
        // Set destroy timestamp
        $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
        // Write and close current session;
        session_write_close();
        // Called after destroy()
        $oldSession = $_SESSION;
        // Start session with new session ID
        session_id($newSessionId);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION = $oldSession;
        // New session does not need them
        unset($_SESSION['destroyed'], $_SESSION['new_session_id']);
    } else {
        session_start();
    }
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    $this->storage->init($_SESSION ?? []);

    if ($this->sessionConfig->getUseCookies()) {
        try {
            $this->clearSubDomainSessionCookie();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException $e) {
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException $e) {
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Expire the session cookie for sub domains
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException
 */
protected function clearSubDomainSessionCookie()
{
    foreach (array_keys($this->_getHosts()) as $host) {
        // Delete cookies with the same name for parent domains
        if (strpos($this->sessionConfig->getCookieDomain(), $host) > 0) {
            $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
            $metadata->setPath($this->sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
            $metadata->setDomain($host);
            $metadata->setSecure($this->sessionConfig->getCookieSecure());
            $metadata->setHttpOnly($this->sessionConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
            $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie($this->getName(), $metadata);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Expire the session cookie
 *
 * Sends a session cookie with no value, and with an expiry in the past.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException
 */
public function expireSessionCookie()
{
    if (!$this->sessionConfig->getUseCookies()) {
        return;
    }

    $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
    $metadata->setPath($this->sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
    $metadata->setDomain($this->sessionConfig->getCookieDomain());
    $metadata->setSecure($this->sessionConfig->getCookieSecure());
    $metadata->setHttpOnly($this->sessionConfig->getCookieHttpOnly());
    $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie($this->getName(), $metadata);
    $this->clearSubDomainSessionCookie();
}

/**
 * Performs ini_set for all of the config options so they can be read by session_start
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function initIniOptions()
{
    foreach ($this->sessionConfig->getOptions() as $option => $value) {
        $result = ini_set($option, $value);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            $error = error_get_last();
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf('Failed to set ini option "%s" to value "%s". %s', $option, $value, $error['message'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you specify what do you want to do with this override? You may not need an overwrite.

Comment: It's to fix this issue mention there: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14973
The script is working, I've tried it in the core and it worked fine, but I need to do it in app>code

Comment: Can you write the class VENDOR\MODULE\SessionManager.php in the question?

Comment: Here, I edited my question

Comment: do you have any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

If you think the PR is correct, you can apply that patch with this module.
https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches

To retrieve the patch of the PR, it is the URL ending **.patch**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14973.patch

The idea is:

1. Install the new module
2. Download the patch
3. Upload it to local folder
4. Update the configuration in **composer.json** as the doc of the module indicate.
5. Apply the patch.

Magento documentation on this approach can be found here:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on Git command:
First, you create 2 .patch file in `patches` folder in magento root folder.
For example: My project named "magento_project". So the .patch file should be created in "htdocs/magento_project/patches/sessionmanager.patch"
Here is my patch file i've created for magento 2.1.10 to fix "empty cart" issue ( check the link to know how to fix "empty cart" issue)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_project\patches\sessionmanager.patch

```
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
@@ -468,12 +468,23 @@
         if ($this->isSessionExists()) {
-            $oldSessionId = session_id();
-            session_regenerate_id();
-            $newSessionId = session_id();
-            session_id($oldSessionIds);
-            session_destroy();
-
-            $oldSession = $_SESSION;
-            session_id($newSessionId);
-            session_start();
-            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
+            $oldSessionId = session_id();
+            session_regenerate_id();   //regen the session
+            $new_session_id = session_id();
+
+            $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
+
+            // Set destroy timestamp
+            $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
+
+            // Write and close current session;
+            session_commit();
+            $oldSession = $_SESSION;   //called after destroy - see destroy!
+            // Start session with new session ID
+            session_id($new_session_id);
+            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 0);
+            session_start();
+            ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
+            $_SESSION = $oldSession;
+            // New session does not need them
+            unset($_SESSION['destroyed']);
+            unset($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
         } else {
\ No newline at end of file
```

> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_project\patches\sessionmanager2.patch

```
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
@@ -185,7 +185,19 @@
             $this->registerSaveHandler();

-            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
-            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
-            session_start();
-            $this->validator->validate($this);
+            if (isset($_SESSION['new_session_id'])) {
+             // Not fully expired yet. Could be lost cookie by unstable network.
+             session_commit();
+             session_id($_SESSION['new_session_id']);
+             }
+            // potential custom logic for session id (ex. switching between hosts)
+            $this->setSessionId($this->sidResolver->getSid($this));
+            session_start();
+            if (isset($_SESSION['destroyed'])) {
+               if ($_SESSION['destroyed'] < time()-300) {
+                   $this->destroy(['clear_storage' => true]);
+
+               }
+            }
+            $this->validator->validate($this);
+

             register_shutdown_function([$this, 'writeClose']);
\ No newline at end of file
```

Okay, the reason i created 2 file because when i put them in one file, it will cause an error `patch fragment without header` which i still dont know how to fix.
After create this 2 patch file, open command line in your magento root folder, which in mine case is "magento_project".
And type `git apply patches/sessionmanager.patch` and `git apply patches/sessionmanager2.patch`.

If you got error when running this command, and it say something about line 468 and line 185, it highly because of your `SessionManager.php` in your project is different than mine.
Please check again in patch file and change so it look like `SessionManager.php` in your project.
Oh, and dont forget to check the `white space` in patch file. **Its really important**. The `white space` of patch file is always = `white space` in `SessionManager.php` +1, accept for the line which have + and - at the beginning of the line.

That's it. Thanks for reading. Hope it help some one :)
Gonna update if i know something else